# Turn Coldfusion Query Results Into X-Editable Data-Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion, x-editable

I'm using the plugin `x-editable` and I'm trying to figure out how to load a list of State names into a select list for inline editing.

Basically, I've queried the database:

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn.recAppTest#" name="states">
    SELECT * FROM dbo.states ORDER BY StateName ASC
</cfquery>
```

And I set the HTML:

```
<label class="control-label" for="state">State:
    <a href="##" id="state" data-source="#states#">#session.state#</a>
</label>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('#state').editable({
    name: 'state',
    type: 'select',
    placement: 'right',
    url: 'update-session.cfm',
    send: 'always'
});
```

Note, this does not work, it yields this error:

```
The expression has requested a variable or an intermediate expression result as a simple     
value, however, the result cannot be converted to a simple value. Simple values are   
strings, numbers, boolean values, and date/time values. Queries, arrays, and COM objects 
are examples of complex values. <p> The most likely cause of the error is that you are 
trying to use a complex value as a simple one. For example, you might be trying to use a 
query variable in a cfif tag.
```

The data-source attribute for this plugin only accepts arrays, or objects (arrays preferred because objects can lose ordering).

So how do I turn my coldfusion query into a "javascript array" to use as a datasource?

My only thought is to "construct" a string that matches the array syntax, but Im trying to avoid something like that

Comment: You cannot simply pass a ColdFusion query object to your markup. You will need to massage the data to get it into a format that the plugin is expecting.

Comment: Yes I know, that's my question: how do I do that? I just wrote a function that has a return format "JSON" but that doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to pass JSON into your `data-source` attribute

```
<label class="control-label" for="state">State:
  <a href="##" id="state" data-source="#serializeJSON(states)#">#session.state#</a>
</label>
```

You may need to do more manipulation to the query to get it working how you want, but at a minimum the `data-source` attribute needs JSON

Comment: I literally just found that!! It worked to an extent -- but it's giving me this new error in the JS Console: `GET http://www1.dev/recruitmentapp2/rcc/%7B?_=1381855736794 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: that's a completely separate issue. Does that file exist on the server?

Comment: No, I don't even know what it means. It points to the jquery-1.10.2.js file when I click on the link to inline edit the list.